# Add a DateTimePicker to a Button

Tags: java, javafx, datetimepicker

I am trying to implement a `CalendarPicker` so that it will open in a new window when i press a `Button`in JavaFX

I have added some code for my calendar:

```
@FXML
 public void dateTimePicker(Stage primaryStage){
    CalendarPicker dateTime = new CalendarPicker();
    dateTime.withCalendar(Calendar.getInstance());
    dateTime.withShowTime(Boolean.TRUE);
    dateTime.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    dateTime.calendarProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Calendar>() {

        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Calendar> ov, Calendar t, Calendar t1) {
            System.out.println("Selected date: "+t1.getTime().toString());
        }
    });
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(dateTime);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Date & Time from JFXtras 2.2");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Then added a button to my FXML

```
<Button id="dateTimePicker" fx:id="dateTimePicker" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="398.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" />
```

and finally initialised my `Button`

```
@FXML
private Button dateTimePicker,
```

My button doesn't actually do anything- no new windows open.  I don't get any errors but I do get a warning in Eclipse

```
Parameter 'primaryStage' is not assignable to javafx.event.Event
```

What have I done wrong?

**EDIT**

Adding `onAction` attribute to button has stopped my application running. The error is:

```
 Error resolving onAction='#dateTimePicker', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
```

Comment: Can you fix the FXML snippet? I'm guessing you have `fx:id="openComportButton"` and `onAction="#dateTimePicker"`. Is that right? And what, exactly, are you trying to do? When the user presses the button, what's supposed to happen?

Comment: Oops good spot I copied the wrong code into my question.  I am trying to press a button to open up a dateTimePicker so that the user can select a start date.

Comment: So what I am saying is the dateTimePicker should open in a new window.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question accordingly? Fix the FXML, clarify what you mean.

Comment: There is no `onAction` attribute on the `<Button .../>`?

Comment: Ok that should make more sense now.

Comment: I'm assuming the Java code you are showing is in your controller class, and the controller is specified in the FXML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a controller set up for the FXML file, and the `dateTimePicker()` method is defined in that controller.

First, you need to map the action for the button to the method you defined using the `onAction` property of the button:

```
<Button id="dateTimePicker" fx:id="dateTimePicker" onAction="#dateTimePicker" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="398.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" />
```

The handler method either needs to take a parameter matching the type of event that is generated (`ActionEvent` for [`onAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-)), or no parameters. This is the cause of the warning you're getting in Eclipse. Since you don't need to access the event itself, just define the method to take no parameters:

```
@FXML
public void dateTimePicker(){

    // ...
}
```

Finally, if you want to show a new window, you have to create a new window. So:

```
@FXML
public void dateTimePicker(){
    CalendarPicker dateTime = new CalendarPicker();
    dateTime.withCalendar(Calendar.getInstance());
    dateTime.withShowTime(Boolean.TRUE);
    dateTime.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    dateTime.calendarProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Calendar>() {

        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Calendar> ov, Calendar t, Calendar t1) {
            System.out.println("Selected date: "+t1.getTime().toString());
        }
    });
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(dateTime);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setTitle("Date & Time from JFXtras 2.2");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```